# Spring Boot logback-spring.xml not logging application logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I use spring boot 2.3.1 version, and I have an issue with application logs. My logback-spring.xml file as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APP_LOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} %-5level %-12X{process} %-30([%thread]) %-29logger - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.sample" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APP_LOGGER"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My controller is,

```
package com.sample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@RestController
public class Controller {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

  @GetMapping("/")
  public void greetings(){
    LOGGER.info("AAAAA....");
    LOGGER.debug("DDDD...");
    LOGGER.warn("WWW...");
    LOGGER.error("EEEE....")
  }

}
```

I tried adding the below in application.properties file,

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.com.sample=DEBUG
```

no luck, and also tried with other alternative approach as below, and added file path `logging.file.name=/var/log/app.log` in `application.properties`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="com.sample" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

app.log file is creating and I see only spring related logs, not application logs in the app.log file.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration works well. Remove the logging configuration from the `application.properties`. And you need to hit the baseURL`(example: http://localhost:8080/)` for watching the logs defined inside the controller.
I modified the `logback.xml` a little bit for using a variable for the log directory.
Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="/home/none47/logs"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APP_LOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} %-5level %-12X{process} %-30([%thread]) %-29logger - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.sample" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APP_LOGGER"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yeah that's strange but i made mixed approach, console appender from Spring Console appender and File appender from ch.qos. It got working now. Thanks for your input.